# UITableView resize with auto layout on rotation

Tags: ios, uitableview, rotation, autolayout

I have some weird bug and I can't find the solution.

I have UITableView using auto layout. (Snap to the parent in all 4 sides). 
If I rotate device, it get rendered correctly but if I try to scroll it scroll onelly on left side of the screen.

[image]

The red square is scrolling area.

The next problem which I assume is connected whit this one is when I try to add UIView as subView to UITableView.

if I add :

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 200, self.table.frame.size.width, 5);
UIView * mainView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
mainView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.table addSubview:mainView];
```

is ok, but if I do like :

```
UIView * mainView = [[UIView alloc]init];
mainView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
mainView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.table addSubview:mainView];

[self.table addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(200)-[mainView(20)]" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_table, mainView)]];

[self.table addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[mainView]|" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_table, mainView)]];
```

getting na error :

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView layoutSublayersOfLayer:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2903.23/UIView.m:8540
```

Comment: can you give different color to your view which is added in table view and see how it is rendered in landscape mode?

Comment: Yes, originally I painted view red, I just didn't copy that part of the code :D

Comment: The added view should hidden your table view. I don't know for what purpose you are using so. You might be intended to do that anyway. But my suggestion is, you can add the main view as UITableView's footer view. I think it can give a solution..

Comment: No, I need to add It as a subView

Answer (score 2):

For Autolayout turned on - ( Dont set any frames - it will give weird behavior )

**Your Autolayout constraints should be as follows:**

**Your Autolayout is turned on**

[image: Your Autolayout is turned on]

[image: Your constraints should like this]

if you turn off autolayout you dont required do any sort of change to your storybord or code

Comment: I know that. Pleas read question again. I turned auto layout on as you posted and when rotated, it look ok, but scrolling area is not.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to set a random estimatedRowHeight and it seems to fix the bug. It's likely to be an bug from Apple. Swift version:

```
class MyTableView: UITableView {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        self.estimatedRowHeight = 120
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also just set a height constraint and it will also fix it, for whatever the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Here use

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 200, self.table.bounds.size.width, 5);
```

in place of

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 200, self.table.frame.size.width, 5);
```

Comment: My problem is that scrolling area is not the same that displayed area, using auto layout. For that I don't use frames at all.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the orientation changes of the superview are not getting passed along to your child (tableView). Try putting the following in willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterf‌​aceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration

```
self.tableView.frame = self.view.bounds;
```

I was having a similar issue with a UITableView in a container view that wasn't properly scrolling when rotating to portrait to landscape. Only a small sliver of the table was scrollable. After that, it all works well.